# How to have fig.canvas.draw() in a callback function ROS?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ros

I am trying to make a visualization of a message in ros, but I can't put fig.canvas.draw() in the callback. My goal was a continually updating graph. But each time I try it I get the error "main thread is not in main loop". How do I solve this?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random



from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan

x = np.linspace(0, 2* np.pi, 100)
y=np.random.random_integers(1, 100, 100)

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')

def callback(scan):
    distance_list = scan.ranges
    print(distance_list)
    print("scan angle min", scan.angle_min)
    print("scan angle incr", scan.angle_increment)
    print("scan angle max", scan.angle_max)
    line1.set_ydata(distance_list)
    fig.canvas.draw()

rospy.init_node('lidar_visual_node')
sub = rospy.Subscriber('\scan', LaserScan, callback)

rospy.spin()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the callback is running in a separate thread and doesn't have access to the `fig` in the main thread. An object containing the callback and the required variables could solve this problem by introducing persistence.

```
class Visualiser:
 def __init__(self):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2* np.pi, 100)
    y = np.random.random_integers(1, 100, 100)
    plt.ion()
    self.fig = plt.figure()
    ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')

 def scanner_callback(self, scan):
    distance_list = scan.ranges
    print(distance_list)
    print("scan angle min", scan.angle_min)
    print("scan angle incr", scan.angle_increment)
    print("scan angle max", scan.angle_max)
    self.line1.set_ydata(distance_list)
    self.fig.canvas.draw()


rospy.init_node('lidar_visual_node')
vis = Visualiser()
sub = rospy.Subscriber('\scan', LaserScan, vis.scanner_callback)
rospy.spin()
```

Comment: I tried this out but I still get: RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop